# How to add randomness in each iteration of tensorflow DataSet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm using the Estimator API. I want to process each minibatch (or each element) dynamically in each iteration through the `DataSet`.

For example, I would like to add random noise to each element in the dataset every time it is batched and fed into the `model_fn`.

`dataset.map()` seems to get called only once, and subsequent passes via `dataset.repeat()` are static. This is what I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random 

dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
dx = dx.map(lambda x: x + random.uniform(0, 1)).repeat(2)
for next_element in dx:
    print(next_element.numpy())
```

Output

```
10.426203
20.426203
30.426203
10.426203
20.426203
30.426203
```

One way to do this is to add randomness to the raw data which are read by `input_fn`, but then data won't change between different epochs.

Answer (score 2):

There is some problem with your understanding on `map` function. Map function applies the logic inside it separately to every element but the dataset is created only once. `random.uniform(0, 1)` generates a random float value. So when you make use of `random.uniform()` inside the map function, the dataset is created with a fixed numeric float constant. Now, each time this same numeric float will get added to each element inside the map function.

To overcome that problem, you have to make use of `tf.random.uniform()` which will chain a tensor into the dataset. This tensor will get evaluated every time the `map` function is applied on each element generating different random values though the dataset is created only once.

So your code should be:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
dx = dx.map(lambda x: x + tf.random.uniform([], 0, 1)).repeat(2)
for next_element in dx:
    print(next_element.numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and explanation. To make sure I understand it correctly, the `tf.random.uniform` tensor is evaluated (hence generating a new random number) every time it is called in the graph. It's value is not determined in the `input_fn`, but rather during computation. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code should give you the desired outcome

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random 

def add_noise(x):
    noise = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1)
    return x + noise

dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
dx = dx.map(add_noise).repeat(2)
for next_element in dx:
    print(next_element.numpy())
```

```
10.931375
20.01276
30.051556
10.825275
20.22412
30.7365
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I can think of is generating the noise first and zipping with repeated dataset. Maybe there are some other better solutions.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random 

dx = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.array([10.0, 20.0, 30.0]))
noise = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randn(6))
dx = dx.repeat(2)
new_dx = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dx, noise))
for next_element in new_dx:
    data = next_element[0]
    ns = next_element[1]
    input_ = data+ns
    print(input_.numpy())

# 10.969622987669728
# 19.77313649149436
# 30.09365081990082
# 9.950256200151752
# 19.36040356387037
# 29.6192768988015
```